# DryIoc: Register with a different Dependency of a Dependency

Tags: .net, dryioc

How can I override a Dependency of a Dependency in a Register-Statement?

For Example:

```
class A {
  public A(IB b) {}
}

class MyService {
  public MyService(A a) {}
}

cnt.Register<MyService>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<IB>(serviceKey: "otherIB")); // ignored by dryioc, because it's a Dependency of Dependency A
cnt.Register<IB, OtherB>(serviceKey: "otherIB");
```

I think it's a simple question, if other explanation needed, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency of dependency is a nested thing which is not visible to the first dependency owner. Otherwise it will break an isolation - why should I know about my dependencies implementation details (their dependencies)?

To fix the code you need to add registration for `A`:

```
cnt.Register<MyService>();
cnt.Register<A>(made: Parameters.Of.Type<IB>(serviceKey: "otherIB"));
cnt.Register<IB, OtherB>(serviceKey: "otherIB");
```

#### Update:

From the other hand, if you want a context based dependency, you can register it with condition:

```
cnt.Register<IB, OtherB>(setup: Setup.With(condition:
    req => req.Parent.Enumerate().Any(p => p.ServiceType == typeof(MyService)));

cnt.Register<IB, DefaultB>(setup: Setup.With(condition:
    req => req.Parent.Enumerate().All(p => p.ServiceType != typeof(MyService)));
```

Comment: My Code was just an example to demonstrate the use case. If i want another configured IB for an A instance just for MyService and a default IB for a default A instance for all my other Service-Implementation (expect MyService), I need to configure another registration for A. This is a Code Duplicationen I wanted to prevent.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the context-based registration example.